# Generating new data using VAE in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have built the following function which takes as input some data and runs a VAE on them:

```
def VAE(data, original_dim, latent_dim, test_size, epochs):
    
    x_train, x_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
    
    # Define the VAE architecture
    #Encoder
    encoder_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(original_dim,))
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoder_inputs)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)

    #--- Custom Latent Space Layer
    z_mean = layers.Dense(units=latent_dim, name='Z-Mean', activation='linear')(x)
    z_log_sigma = layers.Dense(units=latent_dim, name='Z-Log-Sigma', activation='linear')(x)
    z = layers.Lambda(sampling, name='Z-Sampling-Layer')([z_mean, z_log_sigma, latent_dim]) # Z sampling layer

    # Instantiate the encoder
    encoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')

    #Decoder
    latent_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    x = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)

    # Instantiate the decoder
    decoder = tf.keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name='decoder')

    # Define outputs from a VAE model by specifying how the encoder-decoder models are linked
    # Instantiate a VAE model
    vae = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_inputs, outputs=decoder(encoder(encoder_inputs)[2]), name='vae')
    
    # Reconstruction loss compares inputs and outputs and tries to minimise the difference
    r_loss = original_dim * tf.keras.losses.mse(encoder_inputs, decoder(encoder(encoder_inputs)[2]))  # use MSE

    # KL divergence loss compares the encoded latent distribution Z with standard Normal distribution and penalizes if it's too different
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma), axis=-1)

    #VAE total loss
    vae_loss = K.mean(r_loss + kl_loss)

    # Add loss to the model and compile it
    vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
    vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
    
    # train the model
    vae.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

where

```
def sampling(args):
    
    z_mean, z_log_sigma, latent_dim = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim), mean=0., stddev=1., seed=42)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon
```

My question is, if I want to generate new data, by using the above VAE how can I achieve that ?

If I want to sample 100 new data, should I use this

```
   latent_mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[2], axis=0) 
   latent_std = tf.math.reduce_std(encoder(x_train)[2], axis=0)
   latent_sample = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, latent_dim), mean=latent_mean, 
                                    stddev=latent_std)
   generated_data = decoder(latent_sample)
```

or

```
   latent_mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[0], axis=0) 
   latent_std = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.exp(encoder(x_train))[1], axis=0)
   latent_sample = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, latent_dim), mean=latent_mean, 
                                    stddev=latent_std)
   generated_data = decoder(latent_sample)
```

?

Basically should I infer `z_mean` and `z_log_sigma` from the `z` or should I use `z_mean` and `z_log_sigma` directly ? What is the difference ?

Moreover, I have seen that everytime `tf.random.normal` is used to generate new data from the latent space. Why not use lognormal for instance ? Is it because of the KL divergence ?

The end-goal is the distribution of the `generated_data` to be as close as possible to the distribution of the original `data`.

Answer (score 1):

**Q) Basically should I infer z_mean and z_log_sigma from the z or should I use z_mean and z_log_sigma directly ? What is the difference ?**

In this specific VAE architecture, the z_mean and z_log_sigma are outputs of the encoder, which are then used in the sampling layer to generate the latent variable z.

z_mean and z_log_sigma are the parameters of the latent distribution, which is assumed to be a gaussian distribution. The sampling layer uses these parameters to sample from this distribution to generate the latent variable z.

You would use the z_mean and z_log_sigma directly when calculating the KL divergence loss, which compares the encoded latent distribution (approximated by z_mean and z_log_sigma) with a standard normal distribution.

You would use the z variable in the decoder network to generate the output.

> So in short, you should use both of them, z_mean, z_log_sigma and z.

**Q) Moreover, I have seen that everytime tf.random.normal is used to generate new data from the latent space. Why not use lognormal for instance ? Is it because of the KL divergence?**

In the VAE architecture, the encoder network maps the input data to the latent space, represented by the mean and log-variance of a normal distribution (z_mean and z_log_sigma). The sampling step generates new points in the latent space by sampling from this normal distribution using these parameters.

z_mean and z_log_sigma are used as the parameters of the normal distribution from which the latent variables are sampled. In the decoder network, z is used as the input and is then mapped back to the original data space.

Regarding the choice of the normal distribution, it is used because of the KL divergence loss. The KL divergence loss measures the dissimilarity between the encoded latent distribution Z and a standard normal distribution. Therefore, if a different distribution is used, the KL divergence loss would no longer be valid.

```
SORRY FOR COPING THE QUESTION AND USING IT IN THE ANSWER I AM NEW TO STACK OVERFLOW
```